# Manipulating list to become a variable for API call

Tags: python, parameters, tuples

I have a list of longitudes and latitudes.

```
list_lat_long = [40.69113021716633, -74.17789320977796, 40.6443530054402, -74.34847470072029, 40.774062720524796, -73.67030582848912, 40.71410381905342, -73.95113368885083, 31.778799, 119.959693, 50.10810880074701, 14.267756265998923]
```

I want to turn this list into a variable that I can then pass into my API call, which needs to be in the following format:

```
params = {'Content-Type ': 'application/json',  "api_key": REDACTED, "size": "500x500", "markers": "40.6911, -74.1779" "|" "40.6444, -74.3485"}
```

The goal:

```
markers = "40.6911, -74.1779" "|" "40.6444, -74.3485"
params = {"markers": markers}
```

However, I'm getting stuck on how to do this - I wrote the following function:

```
def clean_lat_long(list):
  y = []
  for i in list:
    y.append(round(i, 4))
    w = zip(y[::2], y[1::2])
    q = []
    for i in w:
        q.append(i + (""+ "|",))
  return q
```

This gives me:

```
[(40.6911, -74.1779, '|'), (40.6444, -74.3485, '|'), (40.7741, -73.6703, '|'), (40.7141, -73.9511, '|'), (31.7788, 119.9597, '|'), (50.1081, 14.2678, '|')]
```

Which is close, but I still need to add quotation marks around each long/lat pair and remove the commas separating each item. I also feel like there's a much better way to do this.

Comment: What on earth format is that? What are you trying to pass it to? If it's supposed to be JSON, you'll need to escape the quotes inside the value.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post to be more clear.

Comment: Presumably you mean for https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Markers, in which case that's not actually the correct format.

Comment: @cgp25: You just added additional parameters. Still the format for markers is not a valid type

Comment: Weird, using that format did give me a functioning url, but I see what you're saying. I'm still stuck though :-/

Comment: Why not pass the list of `dict` containing 'lat' and 'lon' key? That will make more sense.

Comment: That's because, as far as Python is concerned, `('foo' 'bar' 'baz' == 'foobarbaz')`; see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```
>>> '|'.join('{:.4f},{:.4f}'.format(lat, long_) for lat, long_ in zip(list_lat_long[::2], list_lat_long[1::2]))
'40.6911,-74.1779|40.6444,-74.3485|40.7741,-73.6703|40.7141,-73.9511|31.7788,119.9597|50.1081,14.2678'
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - thank you everyone for your help.

This is the function that did exactly what I'm looking for (when passing in the list of lats & longs)

```
def input_api(l):
f = []
for i in range(0, len(l)-1):
   parameter = str(l[i][0]) + ' ' + str(l[i][1])+ '|' + str(l[i+1][0]) + ' ' + str(l[i+1][1])
   f.append(parameter)
return f
```